# How to get user specfic details (like webpart, calendars etc) on homepage of the site?

Tags: web-part

We are running a NGO, which has some 30+ centers. And each center will have its own page or site which will be 30 in all.

I want a solution where lists are visible depending upon which user from which center is logging in. Moreover, Webparts content is visible as per user permissions (something like fetch webpart data on user login). I also want details like Announcements, Calendars etc to also show up based on user.

Can someone give me an idea on how to go on this in such a way that homepage is not resource heavy?

Comment: Have you investigated Audience Targeting?

Comment: Totally forgot about it. Looks like AT is the solution. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is simply that the user does not see the other items, then you can leverage audiences. These audiences can be created globally and can be based on properties in Active Directory so that membership is automatically updated as SharePoint refreshes user profile data from AD.

However, if the requirement is that the user *CAN NOT* see the other items at all then you will need per-item or per-list security and will need to create groups, either in SharePoint or active directory and lock the items/Lists to only those groups.  Per-item ACLs can kill performance and there is a hard limit that varies based on which version of SharePoint you are using.

I would strongly recommend audiences over security groups if that is an option.

Comment: Perfect! Audience Targeting is easiest. Tx.